# Select specific column in read_csv by its name

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to select a column by name using either from_csv, read_csv or read_table? I know usecols uses column number so an approach translating a given column name to column position works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also pass a list of column names to usecols.

```
pandas.read_csv('myfile.csv', usecols=["foo", "bar", "baz"])
```